# How to compare lines (having timestamp) within single text file?

Tags: python, file, text

I have text file with below lines:

```
[Thu Jan  3 09:28:11 2019]:(sending publish)
[Thu Jan  3 09:28:14 2019]:(sending publish)
[Thu Jan  3 09:28:17 2019]:(not connect )
[Thu Jan  3 09:28:19 2019]:(sending publish)
[Thu Jan  3 09:28:21 2019]:(sending publish)
```

Now I would like to check the timestamps in the text file whether lines have time difference as 3 seconds with `"sending publish"` term as well.

And if the sending publish is not available, need to print the text within (not connect)

from 4th line onwards, need to check the lines with 3 seconds difference.

I don't find any clue or I don't have any python code to compare lines(having timestamp) within single file as well..

Please do support with any examples / code.

Comment: Hi @NithinDhruvah , please have a look at the guidelines on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @Nathan. please look on my earlier questions on the way how I have asked.. of course here I might have missed few norms on how to ask.., .. apologies to all. Nathan: added to your suggestion, if do u have solution/clue for my question, post the same as well. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get what you've asked correctly, the script you need to build should complete 2 tasks:

1. Reading text from txt file with python
2. Parse the information you need from a line string

## Reading from  a file

Here is sample code for opening and reading txt file in python:

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
for row in f:
  print(row)
```

More information - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

## String Parsing

To do that you can use both string slicing or regular expressions search, here is some information on both:

1. Regular Expressions - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html
2. String Slicing - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

## Edit

You can use datetime package in python to calculate time passed on both dates - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Hope it helps!